# concise way to unpack twice from returned

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is probably a dumb question, but I couldn't find anything from searches.

I know if I want to unpack a returned tuple into multiple variables, the syntax is `A,B = myfunction()`

What if my function is returning a tuple of lists, such as `( [1], [2] )`, and I want to assign to my variables integer `1` and `2` instead of the lists `[1]` and `[2]`? Is there a shorthand one liner for this or do I need to do

```
A, B = myfunction()
A = A[0]
B = B[0]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try `A[0][0]` and `b[0][0]`

Comment: The best thing would be to modify your function so it returns what you want. (If it's yours to modify...)

Comment: copy-paste gone wrong, I meant ``A, B = next(zip(*myfunction()))``

Answer (score 7):

Use the same structure:

```
[A], [B] = myfunction()
```

Demo:

```
>>> def myfunction():
        return ( [1], [2] )

>>> [A], [B] = myfunction()
>>> A
1
>>> B
2
```

---

Regarding DeepSpace's comment that *"this creates 2 new lists"*: It doesn't:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('[A], [B] = myfunction()')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (myfunction)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          1
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (A)
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          1
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (B)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is what creating a list looks like:

```
>>> dis.dis('[A]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (A)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Context matters.

Comment: Totally valid answer, but not very reusable. If OP will ever need different indexes this won't suffice, and also keep in mind this creates 2 new lists for no real reason

Comment: @DeepSpace What two lists do you mean? See the edit. If the lists can be longer, they can use `[A, *_], [B, *_] = myfunction()` (though *this* would indeed create new lists). If they want arbitrary indices, I doubt there's something better than what they're doing.

Comment: @DeepSpace, unpacking is not very reusable.  That's by design.  Unpacking is a way of telling the RHS, "I expect this structure.  If I don't get it, I'll throw a tantrum".

Comment: I would have written `(A,), (B,) = myfunction()` but the effect is the same.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, that compiles to the same (as shown by `dis`). I chose `[]` because I don't like the extra commas and because I wanted to visually mirror the data (where they're lists). And then when I reread [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) due to DeepSpace's comment, I saw that the syntactical construct is called "target *list*", so seems more fitting to me to use "list notation" there.

Answer (score 1):

Use arguments so you can control the indexing from outside.

```
def myfunction(a_index=None, b_index=None):
    ...
    if a_index is None and b_index is None:
        return a, b
    return a[a_index], b[b_index]
```

Then

```
A, B = myfunction(0, 0)
```

This is a reusable solution. If you ever need other indexes:

```
A, B = myfunction(2, 1)
```

This does not support mixing (ie only passing `a_index` or `b_index`) but if you need that behavior you can easily add it.

Comment: Why not, but does it answer the "one-liner" requirement though?

Comment: @CorentinPane IMHO more than `next(zip(*myfunction()()))` It's reusable and conveys more information

Comment: agree, but it's still not a one-liner.

Comment: @CorentinPane `A, B = myfunction(0, 0)` is one-liner. OP already has the function

Comment: Why do you need `next(zip(*myfunction()()))` when @DeepSpace's function returns desired output. @CorentinPane.

Answer (score 0):

One of methods of achieving this result is flattening your data. I would do it following way:

```
def myfunction():
    return ([1],[2])
A,B = (i[0] for i in myfunction())
print(A)  # 1
print(B)  # 2
```

There exist other methods of flattening in Python, but `for` is totally enough for 2D structure used in your case (tuple of lists).